# SASS (CSS) logic vs JQuery(Javascript) logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, css, sass

I am wondering which is better for implementing for loops or simple if logic in constructing a web UI.

For instance in terms of performance will SASS [@for](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while) be better than jQuery's [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Please share your thoughts. I am very interested in learning from your experiences.

My current case is i am trying to rearrange [gridster](http://gridster.net/) grid elements. i can use pure javascript to do so, but after a 2nd thought i wanted to try SASS logic, for example giving certain elements a class that the generated CSS from SASS will make them arranged as predefined.

Comment: SASS is a preprocessor/markup-extension framework to create static CSS, while jQuery is a JavaScript library to manipulate the DOM - two completely different domains?

Comment: ultimatley we need both to achieve a decent desired functionality, however I am wondering from the design perspective where should the logic resides...

Comment: What logic? Control flow? That needs to be done in JS. Or can you show me an example how you'd use SASS to create logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Sass is pre-compiled and served as pure CSS, it is far more performant than using jQuery for a known quantity of elements. Your only performance bottleneck is how much it will increase the size of your CSS.

My recommendation is to use Sass if you are styling less than 30 elements on a page at a time.

Comment: Why and what bottle neck is hit at 30 elements? The alternatives are using inline style attributes and using jQuery's CSS method. jQuery UI's plain CSS file is 1,100 lines, I don't know why you'd say 30.

Comment: I'd say the more elements you want to style at a time the more performant CSS gets?